# Using Geofences with React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I found this plugin: *[react-native-geo-fencing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geo-fencing)*

That will basically take your longitude and latitude and determine if you are in the polygon, but say you have 100 different polygons. It seems to result in really poor performance to loop through all those until you find the polygon you are in.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

I just created a package for geofencing in react native called [react-native-boundary](https://github.com/eddieowens/react-native-boundary). It uses only native code, has a very simple API, is easy to install, and triggers `enter` and `exit` events in foreground or background.

This is very late but thought I'd answer for anyone that stumbles on this thread like I did when I was looking for a solution to the same problem.

Comment: dont use that.. Its a very bad library. Everytime it says native module can not be null as soon as you import this library.

Comment: @RishavKumar, the library is very new and I want to make it as solid as possible. Can you please open an [issue](https://github.com/eddieowens/react-native-boundary/issues/new) so that I can take a look?

Comment: @MattyK14 I did rebuilding and it came across many errors. So i just removed the library

Comment: "Native module cannot be null"

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend that you use this package, it's not up to date and the last commit was a long time ago, instead I use the below algorithm for calculating whether or not a point is in my polygon. My function is as below:

```
point = {latitude: 0, longitude: 0} // example of point
polygonArray = [
  {
    'latitude': 35.787184,
    'longitude': 51.348038,
  },
  {
    'latitude': 35.792754,
    'longitude': 51.383057,
  }
] // example of polygonArray 

_isInPolygon = (point, polygonArray) => {

    let x = point.latitude
    let y = point.longitude

    let inside = false
    for (let i = 0, j = polygonArray.length - 1; i < polygonArray.length; j = i++) {
      let xLat = polygonArray[i].latitude
      let yLat = polygonArray[i].longitude
      let xLon = polygonArray[j].latitude
      let yLon = polygonArray[j].longitude

      let intersect = ((yLat > y) !== (yLon > y)) && (x < (xLon - xLat) * (y - yLat) / (yLon - yLat) + xLat)
      if (intersect) inside = !inside
    }
    return inside
  }
```

If the point is in the polygon this function will return `true` and otherwise it returns `false`. Also you can see the source of algorithm [here](https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu//Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html).

Comment: Was it useful for you?

Comment: Thats useful, but my question is more about figuring out an efficient way to detect the Geofence. The way this code is setup I would have to loop through a lot of different polygons to detect which fence I am in. If that makes sense?

Comment: @VahidBoreiri The link you shared doesn't work. Do you still have some reference for that algorithm

Comment: @AshishSinghRawat I Edited my answer and link is true now.

Answer (score 1):

I think [react-native-geo-fencing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geo-fencing) is fine for geofencing using this easily find user is with in area or not. below I write down a full example of geo fence so you can try.

```
import MapView, { Marker, Overlay, Polygon, Circle } from "react-native-maps";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, ToastAndroid } from "react-native";
import GeoFencing from "react-native-geo-fencing";
export default class GoogleMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      latitude: 0,
      longitute: 0,
      lat: 22.7196,
      lng: 75.8577,
      timestamp: null
    };
    /* markers: [{
        title: 'Captain',
        descripton:"indore",
        latitude:0,
        longitude: 0,
        timestamp: null
       },
      {
        title: 'Captain',
        descripton:"indore",
        latitude: 23.1793,
        longitude: 75.7849

      }]*/
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //-------------------- Start Get current location of user---------//

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitute: position.coords.longitude,
          timestamp: position.timestamp
        });
      },

      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 50000 }
    );
    //-----------------End current location of user--------//

    //-----------------Start geo fencing-------------//

    //-------Set fencing boundary for particular area--------------//
    polygon = [
      { lat: this.state.latitude, lng: this.state.longitute },
      { lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng },
      { lat: 22.7192, lng: 75.852 },
      { lat: this.state.latitude, lng: this.state.longitute }
      // last point has to be same as first point
    ];
    //-----------------End boundary of area--------------------//

    //-----------------another user point-----------//
    let point = {
      lat: 22.7192,
      lng: 75.852
    };

    //-----------------point end of user-------------//

    // set point and polygon on containsLocation method

    GeoFencing.containsLocation(point, polygon)
      .then(() => ToastAndroid.show("User is within area", ToastAndroid.SHORT))
      .catch(() =>
        ToastAndroid.show("User is not within area", ToastAndroid.SHORT)
      );
  }

  //--------------------End geo fencing ------------//

  // console.log("latitude is=="+this.state.latitude);
  // console.log("longitute is=="+this.state.longitute)

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: this.state.latitude,
            longitude: this.state.longitute,
            latitudeDelta: 0.015 * 5,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0121 * 5
          }}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          followUserLocation={true}
          zoomEnabled={true}
          showsScale={true}
        >
          {/*Circle Draw and set radius */}
          <MapView.Circle
            key={(this.state.latitude + this.state.longitute).toString()}
            center={{
              latitude: this.state.latitude,
              longitude: this.state.longitute
            }}
            radius={1500}
            strokeWidth={2}
            strokeColor={"red"}
            fillColor={"rgba(230,238,255,0.5)"}
            // onRegionChangeComplete = { this.onRegionChangeComplete.bind(this) }
          />

          {/*this.state.markers.map(marker => (
        <MapView.Marker
          coordinate={{longitude: marker.longitude, latitude: marker.latitude}}
          title={marker.title}
          description={marker.description}
        />
  ))*/}
          {/* Marker Add */}
          <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={{
              latitude: this.state.latitude,
              longitude: this.state.longitute
            }}
            title={"Captain"}
            description={"indore"}
            //image={require("./images/login-logo.png")}
            //pinColor={"gray"}
          />
          {/* 

          <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={{ latitude: 23.1793, longitude: 75.7849 }}
            title={"Captain"}
            description={"indore"}
            centerOffset={{ x: 20, y: 70 }}
          /> */}

          <Image
            source={require("./images/ic_log_in_top.png")}
            style={{ width: 70, height: 70, marginTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10 }}
          />
          {/*<Overlay 
            image="https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg"
            bounds={[
              [23.1793, 75.7849], 
              [this.state.latitude, this.state.longitute]
            ]}
          />*/}
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  map: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0
  }
});
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geo-fencing is not working anymore
i created a polygon points and picked one location as an point. its saying not within polygon

Comment: This for one lat long , what if I have multiple location and I have to set fencing circle for that ?